# SAPUI5 Expression Binding

Tags: data-binding, sapui5

Is it possible to bind control property to model with dynamic property name, stored, for instance, within another model field? I thought we can use SAPUI5 [Expression Binding](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/guide/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0.html) for this purpose, but it doesn't work: binding in trace window is broken and expression seems to be not evaluated at all.

**XML View**

```xml
<TextArea value="{= ${StackOverflow>/bindTextAreaTo} }" />
```

**Controller**

```js
oModel = this.getView().getModel("StackOverflow");

/*
 * The model have two properties: question and comment
 * I want value of TextArea to be bound to one of them based on some condition
 */

oModel.setProperty("/question", "");
oModel.setProperty("/comment", "");

oModel.setProperty("/bindTextAreaTo", 
    bAsk ? "StackOverflow>/question" : "StackOverflow>/comment" );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, that's currently not possible.

However, there is a simple workaround for what you want to do (see below).
Basically, you create a view model and set some boolean value on the model. This flag is then used in your expression binding to define "dynamically" what property of what model shall be used...

**XMLView**

```
<TextArea value="{= ${view>/ask} ? ${StackOverflow>/question} : ${StackOverflow>/comment} }" />
```

**Controller**

```
var oModel = this.getView().getModel("StackOverflow");
oModel.setProperty("/question", "");
oModel.setProperty("/comment", "");
//...

var oViewModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
this.getView().setModel(oViewModel, "view);
//...

oViewModel.setProperty("/ask", bAsk);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also found another SO answer with similar approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653740/how-to-use-an-if-else-condition-in-a-sapui-xml-view

Comment: Well, this workaround works with two values only, but what if one has 100 possibilities for a different value?