# Dynamically render View Element with SAP UI5

Tags: sapui5

How can i use if/else conditions to render any view dynamically in UI5. 
i found this, which seemed for me a proper solution:

[How to use an if-else condition in a SAPUI5 XML-View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653740/how-to-use-an-if-else-condition-in-a-sapui5-xml-view)

But this does not work because the xmlns attribute xmlns:template="http://schemas.sap.com/sapui5/extension/sap.ui.core.template/1"

does not work.

So how to solve this problem? I did not found any other template link.

Comment: I use the second approach of the Content of the link.It is more complicated but the first approach does not work.

Comment: The first approach ([XML templating](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/5ee619fc1370463ea674ee04b65ed83b)) is currently not supported with routing. But it's in the roadmap.

Comment: ok, nice to know. How do you know that?

Comment: You mean that it's in the roadmap? You can see roadmaps for SAP products in https://www.sap.com/products/roadmaps/finder-all.html. Search by "ui5" for SAPUI5 roadmap. You need an account though. For OpenUI5, it's in https://openui5.org/OpenUI5_Roadmap.pdf

Comment: this never worked. Don't do it. Every aggregation can have a factory function. Everything else is to complex

Comment: Agree with @bkr. Even if the router supports XML templating, it's an overkill and too static (the template tags apply only once during the view instantiation). If the amount of the target controls is small, simply switching the visibility of them might be a good-enough but maintainable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Expression binding](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0.html)

Example:

```
<Text text="I am text" visible={= ${viewModel>/bIsTextVIsible} || ${viewModel>/bAnotherCondition} } />
```